# Black noise around edges of an object in cycles render

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I was just trying to bake a normal map for this mask model. The scene looks as follows:

[image: Basic Blender normal map baking layout]

With nothing unusual going on.

I try to test out the scene using cycles, but even without applying the normal map, I get this bizarre noise:

[image: bizar edge noise]
[image: bizar edge noise zoomin]

It looks like the sun light is throwing wrong shadows on the edges, as some of the splotches (though not all) go away when I turn off shadows. I'm thinking there is a problem with the settings for this mesh, though I can't find anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: Did you model this in blender or is this an imported object? Try deleting custom split normals.

Comment: Try decreasing the strength of the normal map node and see what happens.

Comment: @susu It is imported yes, deleing custom split normals leads to random sharp edges appearing over the model, I don't really understand what is going on, but it doesn't seem to fix the problem either way